# Data synchronization between two django applications running on different server and using different databases

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I have one django application running on two different ports of apache.

Both are using different databases but schema is same (because both are same application).

I want a mechanism for **automatic data synchronization** between both databases.

What are the possible ways that I can follow to **automate data synchronization**?

Is there any third party API/Application to do this or writing own code will be better?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [django-synchro](https://github.com/zlorf/django-synchro), a django app for database data synchronization.

I haven't used this app, but looks like it fits your need

> This app is for synchronization of django objects between databases.
>
> It logs information about objects' manipulations (additions, changes, deletions). When synchronization is launched, all objects logged from the last checkpoint are synced to another database.